# Why ArrayList extend elementData array by specific formula?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

Just five minutes ago I found out how `ArrayList` works. It has `elementData` field which is array with specific type, if we add element and `elementData` array is full, collection internally create another array by this formula:

```
(oldCapacity * 3) / 2 + 1
```

And copy data from old array to new one. I`m just wondering, why is that? why not just double last size? where can i get more theoretical information about internal representation of ArrayList collection with describing this formula.
P.S. Sorry for my English, its not my native language.

Comment: Doubling would be quite big growing steps.

Comment: ok doubling is bad, but why this one ?

Comment: grow by about 50% is easy to calculate and I do not see why any other formular would be better.

Comment: I think it would be better if size is increased by 1 after each insertion like a linked list :D

Comment: Growing is expensive (slow) so you want to avoid it to happen often.

Comment: @aacanakin: With that approach, the cost of each insertion would be proportional to the size of the list; so, for example, starting with an empty list and inserting *n* elements would cost O(*n* ²). This would defeat much of the purpose of having array-backed lists to begin with.

Comment: @ruakh: It would indeed. It would also be in direct violation of the `ArrayList` spec.

Comment: @aacanakin The idea is to strike a reasonable compromise between wasted memory, and the number of times you have to copy each list. Clearly, copying the list on every insertion to avoid overhead is not a compromise.

Comment: @ruakh yeah you're right. But I only looked this problem from a memory-friendly perspective

Comment: @aacanakin An array-backed list with a growth factor smaller than 2 will still win over a linked list. That's "memory friendly enough". (Or to be more exact, an array-backed list that's filled to at least half capacity, which should be the common case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the growth policy is unspecified, except that it [guarantees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) that adding an element has a constant amortized cost.

Both the scheme that you propose and the scheme used by your JDK offer such a guarantee. In fact, *any* multiplicative growth scheme would be compliant. Other languages/libraries increase the size by a factor of two, so that too is a common scheme. A different Java implementation could choose to follow that scheme, and still comply with the spec.

See the discussion in [Amortized analysis of std::vector insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550509/amortized-analysis-of-stdvector-insertion) -- it's about C++ but applies equally well to Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no objective measure. We can avoid copying by wasting more memory, or we can save memory by copying more often. These 2 cannot be objectively measured in one goal function.