# Recommended data structure in Julia for efficient append

Tags: julia

What is the ideal list-like data structure in Julia?

I want an indexible, growable, collection with a constant-time append operation.

The standard data structure seems to be `Array` with the `push!` operation.  Is this constant time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Harlan said, `push!` is amortized constant time. See the description of C++'s similar data structure for arguments why: [Amortized analysis of std::vector insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550509/amortized-analysis-of-stdvector-insertion)

If you want a legitimately constant time data structure, you probably want to implement a linked list. I've seen lots of sample implementations, but nothing that's ready for production.

Comment: Amortized constant time is fine with me!  Mostly I was curious.

Answer (score 4):

Repeatedly calling `push!` is not constant time, but it's pretty fast. It does an occasional exponential reallocation of the buffer. See the C source for appending to an array: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/array.c#L564

Answer (score 0):

Difference lists let you append, prepend, and concatenate in constant time. I pushed an implementation yesterday [here](https://github.com/zot/DifferenceLists.jl). It's really just a few lines of code but I made it fancier by adding in support for iteration and display.

You create a difference list with the `dl` function, like this: `dl(1, 2, 3)` or make a difference list for anything you can iterate with `todl(items)`.

You can concatenate any number of difference lists in constant time with the `concat` function, like this: `concat(dl(1, 2), dl(3, 4))`.

You can use `pushfirst` and `push` to add to the start and end in constant time.

Difference lists can iterate so you can use them in for-loops and splats and easily convert them to arrays.

I'm waiting for it to get published as a Julia package but you can just use [the DifferenceLists.jl file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zot/DifferenceLists.jl/master/src/DifferenceLists.jl) directly.