# List class with O(1) operations

Tags: python

I'm in the process of trying to create this kind of list class where each operation would be of O(1). I found that `reverse()` will be of O(1), but it seems that insert is not? Is there a way to accomplish this with pythons standard methods?

```
class TimeList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []

    def push_last(self, x):
        self.arr.insert(len(self.arr), x)

    def push_first(self,x):
        self.arr.insert(0, x)

    def rev(self):
        self.arr.reverse()

    def pop_last(self):
        """
        Remove and return last element
        """
        rem = self.arr[-1]
        self.arr = self.arr[:-1]
        return rem

    def pop_first(self):
        """
        Remove and return first element
        """
        rem = self.arr[0]
        self.arr = self.arr[1:]
        return rem
```

Comment: `.arr.reverse()` is **not** O(1).  Note, your `pop` method is not O(1). Why do you think this is possible, to create a list with all O(1) operations? And if it were, why wouldnt the built-in list do this already?

Comment: Here you can find complexity for different types of data structures:
https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/img/big-o-cheat-sheet-poster.png

Comment: It isn't possible to reverse a list in constant time. Inserting to the front of a standard list is also incredibly expensive, as are operations like `self.arr = self.arr[:-1]` that create an entire copy of `arr`.

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected regarded reversing a list. I guess technically you can simply alter how a list is iterated/added to give the appearance of a reversal, even without any structural changes happening.

Comment: quoting @juanpa.arrivillaga,  If there was a way why wouldn't the original list implement it

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicate but you may create somewhat c++ `vector` like class to have `amortized O(1)` for push/pop front & last.

Below is skeleton code (I don't guarantee it will work properly. Such as [] operator, `len()`, list size getting less than 0 etc.) to show how it works.

Basically, you create list size of `INIT_SIZE` at first, and starting from the middle of the list, you push to the `front_idx` or `back_idx`. If the `idx` reaches 0 or `len(self.arr)` double the size of `self.arr`. This is [proven to be `amortized O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550509/amortized-analysis-of-stdvector-insertion).

Reversing works with `self.is_reversed` flag. So it decides which `idx` class needs to use for front/back push/pop operation. Tricky part is how you will gonna handle `[] operator`. I'll leave that to you for the detail implementation. (Use `front_idx` & `back_idx` wisely based on the `is_reversed` flag.)

```py
class TimeList:
    INIT_SIZE = 100

    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = [None] * TimeList.INIT_SIZE
        self.is_reversed = False
        self.front_idx = TimeList.INIT_SIZE // 2
        self.back_idx = TimeList.INIT_SIZE // 2

    # Implement below two methods in order to make [] operator work properly.
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return

    def __expand_arr(self):
        new_arr = [None] * len(self.arr) * 2
        for i in range(self.front_idx, self.back_idx):
            new_arr[i + (len(new_arr) - len(self.arr)) // 2] = self.arr[i]
        self.front_idx = self.front_idx + (len(new_arr) - len(self.arr)) / 2
        self.back_idx = self.back_idx + (len(new_arr) - len(self.arr)) / 2

    def __insert_front(self, x):
        if self.front_idx == 0:
            self.__expand_arr()
        self.front_idx -= 1
        self.arr[self.front_idx] = x

    def __insert_back(self, x):
        if self.back_idx == len(self.arr):
            self.__expand_arr()
        self.arr[self.back_idx] = x
        self.back_idx += 1

    def push_last(self, x):
        if self.is_reversed:
            self.__insert_front(x)
        else:
            self.__insert_back(x)

    def push_first(self, x):
        if self.is_reversed:
            self.__insert_back(x)
        else:
            self.__insert_front(x)

    def rev(self):
        self.is_reversed = not self.is_reversed

    def __remove_front(self):
        self.front_idx += 1

    def __remove_back(self):
        self.back_idx -= 1

    def pop_last(self):
        """
        Remove and return last element
        """
        if self.is_reversed:
            rem = self.arr[self.front_idx]
            self.__remove_front()
        else:
            rem = self.arr[self.back_idx - 1]
            self.__remove_back()
        return rem

    def pop_first(self):
        """
        Remove and return first element
        """
        if self.is_reversed:
            rem = self.arr[self.back_idx - 1]
            self.__remove_back()
        else:
            rem = self.arr[self.front_idx]
            self.__remove_front()
        return rem
```