What would be the complexity cost of a push back on a dynamically sized container with perfect square integer size?
This came up on an exam, the question asked for the worst-case and amortized complexity cost for a custom dynamically sized container. The container’s size is the next perfect square integer and it only changes when its capacity is exceeded, so it can go from 1 to 4, 4 to 9, 9 to 16, 16 to 25…
I assumed sizes n and n+1, the difference would have been (n+1)^2-(n)^2 which is equal to (2n+1) and I thought it had a time complexity of O(n) but apparently it’s false

There are a few cases where it would be okay to tag both C and C++, and they are listed in their respective tag wiki (C++, C). This question is not one of those cases. There's really no code for this, it seems language-agnostic and more about algorithm than actual code.

Similar: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/why-is-push-back-in-c-vectors-constant-amortized and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550509/amortized-analysis-of-stdvector-insertion

Inserting an n+1 element would result in creating a (n+1)^2 container. Wouldn't that make the complexity O(n^2)?

This looks to me like quadratic worst case (O(n^2)) in the case where the container storage grows, but amortized constant (average O(1) for sequence of insertions). The time it takes to grow the container increases by the square of the number of times it grew in the past, but the number of times you have to grow it also decreases with the square of the number of times it grew in the past.

@FrançoisAndrieux With that logic, linear growth would also result in constant time which clearly isn't the case. You're forgetting that every new size increase also takes more time to copy all existing elements. Also, the container grows when its size is square of a number, not square of the number of elements.

Oh well... the theory. Thing is, std::vector has amortized O(1), and intuitively, so does your container. How to actually explain it, though... the thing is, if your container size is currently m^2, you can put m^2 elements into it, at O(1). Only the next (m^2+1)th element means the container needs to grow, and the existing elements need to be copied, giving us O(n) for this one push. Following that, you can do a whole lot of pushes at O(1) again -- so, there are lots of O(1) pushes and only a select few O(n), which will likely just average into oblivion...

@ChristianStieber std::vector, though, doubles the container size with each re-allocation – that's a huge difference!

Worst-case for a single push_back is, obviously, when it resizes. Since allocation is usually considered O(1), on N elements we'll simply have to move all N existing elements so it's O(N) time.
To estimate amortized complexity you perform N=M² push_back()s and average the time. There will be √N=M reallocations, moving 1²+2²+...+M² = O(M³) elements. When divided by N, average would be O(M) = O(√N).

Nice... I'd have approached differently, by the way: With every growth we allocate O(n) new elements (with the original n from question), but need to copy O(n²) elements, thus on average we get an effort of O(n²)/O(n) = O(n) – and as n is not the container size N, but O(N) = O(n²) then finally O(n) = O(sqrt(N)) gives the same result. Leaving it to the reader to choose his preferred variant ;)
