# How is the capacity of std::vector determined

Tags: c++, stdvector

I know that in std::vector, the size will grow every time it runs out of room.  Yet I'm not noticing a pattern in how it grows. Can someone please explain to me the pattern and why it was chosen.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    vector<int> myVector;
    for(int i =0 ; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        myVector.push_back(i);
        cout << myVector.capacity();
    cout << ", ";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13, 13, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 28, 28, 28, 2
8, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 6
3, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 6
3, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 9
4, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141
```

Comment: It's highly compiler dependedent, but I read somewhere (forgot source though) it grows by factor 2X in some implementations

Comment: This is not standardized, so it depends on the implementation. You can't rely on any patterns.

Comment: You can normally rely on the fact that when capacity is increased, it'll be `new_capacity = old_capacity * some_factor;`. The main area of variation is in the value of `some_factor`. This is normally carried out with integer arithmetic, so for the smaller numbers, rounding tends to hide the underlying pattern.

Comment: If you're using Microsoft's standard library then it increases by a factor of 1.5. Stephan T. Lavavej once said so in one of his online videos about the std.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the implementation, so don't expect the same pattern when you switch the operating system, the compiler, etc.

The most common growth patterns are `1.5 * previous_capacity` and `2 * previous_capacity`. In your example, it seems that it's the former.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100426/784668 for a possible explanation for why that factor was chosen. The point is that it apparently allows reusing free memory blocks that were previously used for storing the array.

Comment: Why was this pattern chosen? Why not for example do it in a Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: A Fibonacci sequence would also end up with O(log N) allocations for N `push_back`s, but is unnecessarily complicated.  Occam's razor.

Comment: I remember reading that *in the absence of other memory allocations* a Fibonacci sequence is actually the best. Something to do with most efficient reuse of freed memory.

Answer (score 1):

It is an implementation detail, you are not supposed co care about it. In your case it seems to be something like

```
i += i/2
```

but somewhat more complex.

Comment: Seems there's no `+1` in general.  Must be a special case for 1 -> 2.

Comment: I believe it's `i += i/2` since `3` progresses to `4`.