# What is the average overallocation factor of an array that grows by doubling its size?

Tags: arrays, list, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

In .Net the `List<T>` type will resize itself automatically, by doubling the capacity of its internal buffer, every time it gets full.
As a result, some memory is wasted.
(I do not know the item count in advance, it is random, and I cannot resize manually after all items are added.)

Can we tell **how much memory is wasted, on average, by the "doubling" allocation strategy**?

---

Here's my attempt at finding the answer. I [just read a blog](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2013/12/02/using-stl-vectors/) that asserts that the capacity ends up being on average 1.5 times the actual final required buffer size, but there is no explanation. I suppose the reasoning goes like this:

- with 2^n items, there is no overallocation: f=1
- with (2^n)+1 items, there is an overallocation of nearly f=2

So on average, it would follow that the overallocation factor is f=1.5... But while it is obvious that the lower and upper bounds are f=1 and f=2, I am not convinced that it follows that 1.5 is the correct average.
My feeling is that the distribution of actual sizes could not be uniform between each power of two. If we use the Pareto distribution, is it really 1.5? It's been so long since my last math classes, I can't tell...

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100311/what-is-the-ideal-growth-rate-for-a-dynamically-allocated-array) is related but only address the growth rate, not the amount of wasted memory.

Comment: Average over what, exactly? For example, are you assuming the list is being appended to at each iteration, and you're trying to find the average memory wasted throughout this entire time? Or is the list being used differently?

Comment: I was thinking, averaged over "typical random input". I think the Pareto distribution can be used to model this... For your example, constant appending, I am pretty sure the average waste is 1.5.

Comment: Assuming a Pareto distribution, I think the correct average value will be the integral from 0 to 1 of 2^x, which works out I think to be 1/log(2), or ~1.442695.  Or, for all practical purposes, 1.5.

Comment: "Typical random input" confuses me, because it really depends on what you call your "input". To me, the "input" here is a sequence of *commands* which are either *insertions* or *removals* (at arbitrary indices). Are you (uniformly) randomly choosing between insertions and removals, and also (uniformly) randomly choosing an index? How do you define a random input?

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear, I define "random input" as "random item counts". I do only appends.

Comment: @supercat, I think there's something wrong in your formula. For a list with a growth factor of 3, 1/log(3) gives me 0.91, which is unexpectedly not between 1 and 3.

Comment: @EldritchConundrum: The formula I gave was for a growth factor of two.  I believe the general formula for a growth factor of n would be (n-1)/log(n).  In the case of growth-factor 2, the n-1 factor evaluates to 1, but for a growth factor of 3 it would evaluate to 2.  For larger growth factors, the difference between the Pareto average and the (min+max)/2 average becomes significant [e.g. with 10:1 growth the average is 3.9 rather than 5.5]; my main point was that for 2:1 the difference is pretty trivial.

Comment: @supercat: Interesting. I would accept that as an answer, if it was presented as one :)