# Stack constructor - What to put as initial capacity?

Tags: c#, performance, stack

One of the constructors shown on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h9ztet0(v=vs.110).aspx), takes an `Int32` parameter representing the initial capacity.

There is also a remark on the above documentation page which states the following:

> If Count is less than the capacity of the stack, Push is an O(1) operation. If the capacity needs to be increased to accommodate the new element, Push becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count. Pop is an O(1) operation.

I'm in a situation where I don't really know how much initial capacity to give my stack. Is it better to overestimate what you think you need ? Because surely a too low initial capacity would make the performance suffer?

What is the drawback in passing in a high initial capacity in terms of performance?

Answer (score 3):

Internally, the storage array inside [`Stack<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs#166d51735eb29246#references) grows [exponentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831998/lists-double-their-space-in-c-sharp-when-they-need-more-room-at-some-point-does/24832862#24832862), which implies an [amortized O(1) cost to add an element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost).  So, if you don't know the correct initial capacity, don't worry about it and use the [default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3wdkyac%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the performance will be good anyway.

Comment: Ok so then default initial capacity will be set to 10, as far as I understand. So if you add/push an 11th item, will the internal array be copied to a new array 2 times bigger than the current internal array?

Comment: Yes, it will.  And a similar the copy will on when you push the 21st item, 41st, and so on.  However, quoting Wikipedia, " Expanding the array by any constant proportion ensures that inserting n elements takes O(n) time overall, meaning that each insertion takes amortized constant time."  Worrying about the initial capacity of a stack may be [premature optimization](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/09/06/the-premature-optimization-is-evil-myth/).  Do you know you have a performance problem?

Comment: Ok I understand now. Yes I do have a performance problem - but seems like I can eliminate my stack initialization, from the list of potential culprits. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @D.Singh if you know you have a performance problem, I would recommend using a good profiler to identify where it is, rather than using trial and error.   In my previous job I was able to use the [dotTrace profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) to good effect; Visual Studio also has a [built-in profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx). A good profiler will tell you exactly where you code is spending time method-by-method or even line-by-line and will tell you if you are getting unlucky with your stack copies.