# why so many copying while transforming/copying vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, copy-constructor

Why so many calls to copy cons, i would expect only last nine of them? Or even not at all duy to return value optimization.

```
struct C
{
    int _i;
    C(int i) : _i(i) {}
    C(const C& other) { cout << "copy cons from " << other._i << " to " << _i << endl; _i = other._i; }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<int> vi{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    vector<C> vc;
    transform(vi.begin(), vi.end(), back_inserter(vc), 
        [](int i) 
    { 
        return C(i); 
    });
}
```

Output:

```
copy cons from 1 to - 842150451
copy cons from 1 to - 842150451
copy cons from 2 to - 842150451
copy cons from 1 to - 842150451
copy cons from 2 to - 842150451
copy cons from 3 to - 842150451
copy cons from 1 to - 842150451
copy cons from 2 to - 842150451
copy cons from 3 to - 842150451
copy cons from 4 to - 842150451
copy cons from 1 to - 842150451
copy cons from 2 to - 842150451
copy cons from 3 to - 842150451
copy cons from 4 to - 842150451
copy cons from 5 to - 842150451
copy cons from 6 to - 842150451
copy cons from 1 to - 842150451
copy cons from 2 to - 842150451
copy cons from 3 to - 842150451
copy cons from 4 to - 842150451
copy cons from 5 to - 842150451
copy cons from 6 to - 842150451
copy cons from 7 to - 842150451
copy cons from 8 to - 842150451
copy cons from 9 to - 842150451
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your vector `vc` has to grow a few times. Each time it does that, it allocates a larger memory block, and copies the original elements over.

You can stop it from doing that by reserving enough space using `std::vector::reserve`.

```
vector<C> vc;
vc.reserve(vi.size());
```

Comment: Yeh, thanks, it is true, but why it grows so slowly, but not e.g. by factor of two every time? Isn't it a bit silly?

Comment: @Yola It grows by some factor close to two. The exact factor depends on the implementation.

Comment: the main reason many implementations use a growth factor closer to the golden ratio (~1.62) than to 2 is that this can prevent memory fragmentation. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1100426/358277) for a more in depth explanation

Answer (score 4):

As it is seen from the program output when a new element is added to the vector then the memory is reallocated and already existent elements of the vector are copied in new locations.

You can reserve enough memory before running the algorithm that to avoid memory reallocation.

```
vector<C> vc;
vc.reserve( vi.size() );
```

In this case redundent calls of the copy constructor could be avoided.

But it is not the full story.:)

Class C has a conversion constructor

```
C(int i) : _i(i) {}
```

It allows to simplify creating elements of vector `vc` by substituting the call of the algorithm `std::transform` that uses a lambda expression for algorithm `std::copy` without using a lambda expression. For example

```
std::copy( vi.begin(), vi.end(), std::back_inserter( vc ) );
```

But even this is not the full story.:)

When you use either `std::transform` or `std::copy` then there are used two constructors: the constructor with a parameter and the copy construtor.

You could avoid using the copy construtor and achieve a more efficient result. Simply instead of method `push_back` it is better to use method `emplace_back`

How to use this method?

The simplest one is to use the range-based for statement

```
for ( int x : vi ) vc.emplace_back( x );
```

It is enough clear and readable.

If you want to use a standard algorithm you could write

```
std::for_each( vi.begin(), vi.end(), [&vc]( int x ) { vc.emplace_back( x ); } );
```

In the both cases only the constructor with a parameter will be called avoiding calling the copy constructor.

Check it yourself.:)

Comment: Thank you for such elaborate answer.

Comment: @Yola I hope it is an interesting and useful answer.:)