# Amortized Analysis [Dynamic Array]

Tags: array-algorithms, amortized-analysis

Let x be the size of an empty array. If the array grows full, a new one will be created with a length k > x. The contents of the old array will be copied to the new one, and the new element will be stored as well.

- An array with length k is created in k steps
- Copying an element takes constant time.

Question:
How do you choose k so that each insert operation has amortized constant time, and the insertion of n elements takes Θ(n)? Prove your assumption that your choice results in constant amortized time per insert operation with amortized analysis.

My gut feeling says k = 2*n would be a good idea but I have no idea how to prove it. I don't think I understood amortized analysis at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Divide the total number of steps by the total number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Growing exponentially is better than constant growth. But whether to grow it by factor 2 or by factor 2.1 there is no hard rule. Please check url below for further details.

[What is the ideal growth rate for a dynamically allocated array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100311/what-is-the-ideal-growth-rate-for-a-dynamically-allocated-array)