# To what lengths should I go in order to avoid raising `FE_INEXACT` in library code?

Tags: c, floating-point-exceptions

I'm creating a library in C that contains common data structures, convenience functions, etc. that is intended for general use. Within, I've implemented a dynamic array, and I've chosen the golden ratio as the growth factor for the reason explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20481237/6526693). However, this necessarily involves multiplication of floating-point numbers, which can cause `FE_INEXACT` to be raised if they have large significands.

When I implemented it, I was under the impression that, as the library is for general use, floating point exceptions must be avoided if at all possible. I first tried something like

```
fenv_t fenv;
feholdexcept(&fenv);
// expand dynamic array
feclearexcept(FE_INEXACT);
feupdateenv(&fenv);
```

, but this had such an enormous time cost that it wasn't worth it.

Eventually, I came up with a solution that had negligible time cost. While not avoiding `FE_INEXACT` entirely, it made it highly unlikely. Namely,

```
size_t newCapacity = nearbyint((double)(float)PHI * capacity);
```

This would only raise `FE_INEXACT` if the current capacity was extremely large, at least for compilers that adhere to IEEE 754 standards.

I'm starting to wonder whether my efforts have gone into solving a relative nonissue. For library code, is it reasonable to expect the user to handle the raising of `FE_INEXACT` when necessary, or should it be avoided within the library? In the latter case, how important is the issue compared to other factors, such as efficiency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To what lengths should I go...

None at all. Almost nobody uses `fenv.h`, compilers do not even fully support it (they make transformations that wrongly disregard or alter the floating point environment), and if someone calling your code is using it, it's completely reasonable to require them to save/restore exception state around calls to your library. Moreover, most of the time if you're doing an operation that raises `FE_INEXACT`, it's *precisely because* the result you're going to be returning is inexact, and it's thereby semantically appropriate to be raising it.