# Vector with large element

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, stl, containers

Lets say we have 1 million elements stored in our `std::vector<T>`, its capacity is full.
Now I just want to add 1 element in it. According to concept of vector, now vector's capacity will be doubled in the new memory in heap and all 1 million elements will be copied to new memory location.
This seems to be a huge task.
Is here there any way that I can avoid this copying and add this new element in the next location only?

Nothing. I cant think of any method to avoid. Most developers suggested me use another container.

Comment: There are no rules that say that the reallocation have to double. It's up to the individual implementations.

Comment: Also, if the elements are movable, that saves the copying.

Comment: What requirements do you have of this container?  Your requirements should dictate whether "use another container" is correct.  If you need elements to be contiguous in memory, `std::vector` is probably correct and `std::vector::reserve()` can avoid the problem you describe.

Comment: This is not possible - "add this new element in the next location only" makes absolutely no sense. If this is not okay for you then use a different type of container.

Answer (score 5):

> According to concept of vector, now vector's capacity will be doubled in the new memory in heap and all 1 million elements will be copied to new memory location.

This is not quite correct. Most implementations of `std::vector` have a growth factor of about `1.5` instead of `2.0`. See this question for further information:

[What is the ideal growth rate for a dynamically allocated array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1100311/12149471)

You can control the capacity and its growth using [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). That way, it may be possible for you to prevent the need for the entire content of the container to be copied.