# What's the proper way to store a text file line by line in an array in C?

Tags: c

I have a text file with variable length lines which I would like to store in a dynamic array using c.

The following is the dynamic array implementation:

```
struct array {
    char **elements;
    long size;
    long capacity;
};

void array_init(struct array *array, long capacity)
{
    array->capacity = capacity;
    array->elements = malloc(capacity * sizeof(char*));
}

void array_push_back(struct array *array, char *element)
{
    if (array->size == array->capacity) {
        array->capacity *= 2;
        array->elements = realloc(array->elements, array->capacity * sizeof(char*));
    }
    array->elements[array->size++] = element;
}
```

I read the file via the following:

```
struct array array;
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
const unsigned MAX_LENGTH = 256;
char buffer[MAX_LENGTH];

array_init(&array, 1000);

while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LENGTH, file))
{
     array_push_back(&array, buffer);
}

for (int i = 0; i < array.size; i++)
{
     printf(array.elements[i]);
}
```

`printf` prints the last element only as many times as large the array is. I guess it is because I assign `buffer`'s address to `array.elements[i]` and only change the content of `buffer`.

Can someone please help with correctly reading from a file and storing it?

Comment: where is your format specifier for printf?  Maybe read the docs

Comment: Doesn't `array.elements` just contain a whole bunch of pointers to the same buffer?

Comment: `array->elements[array->size++] = element;` - it's the same pointer every time.

Comment: Yeah this is the odd part `array->elements[array->size++] = element;`.
You should copy contents of `buffer` (i.e., `element`) to `array->elements[array->size++]`. For instance, use `memcpy`.

Comment: Your method will store a line as multiple consecutive array elements if a line's length exceeds MAX_LENGTH.

Comment: The function `array_init` should set `array->size` to `0`. Otherwise, it has an indeterminate variable (which may happen to be `0`, but may also be something else).

Comment: Side note: Doubling the size of the array may not be the ideal growth rate. A better factor than `2.0` may be `1.5`. See this question for further information: [What is the ideal growth rate for a dynamically allocated array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1100311/12149471)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> array->elements[array->size++] = element;
> ```

You are storing a *pointer* to `buffer` from `main` over and over again to each element. You have to copy the *content* of the string.

```
array->elements[array->size++] = strdup(element);
```

or:

```
const size_t n = strlen(element);
array->elements[array->size] = malloc(n + 1);
memcpy(array->elements[array->size], element, n + 1);
array->size++;
```

Comment: `strdup` was a perfect fit in here since it both allocates memory and copies the string.

Comment: It's very important to follow @Andreas Wenzel correction in the comments section too.

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop in main

```
char buffer[MAX_LENGTH];

array_init(&array, 1000);

while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LENGTH, file))
{
     array_push_back(&array, buffer);
}
```

you are passing the same array `buffer` to the function `array_push_back`. So the function gets a pointer to the first element of array. And within the function all dynamically allocated pointers are set with this address

```
array->elements[array->size++] = element;
```

You need to allocate dynamically a character array for each pointer and copy the string stored in the array `buffer` into the dynamically allocated array.

Pay attention to that this function

```
void array_init(struct array *array, long capacity)
{
    array->capacity = capacity;
    array->elements = malloc(capacity * sizeof(char*));
}
```

does not initialize data member `size` to zero of the passed structure. It stays uninitialized.

And using the same pointer `array->elements` in the left and the right sides of the assignment in this statement

```
array->elements = realloc(array->elements, array->capacity * sizeof(char*));
```

is unsafe. The function can return a null pointer and the early allocated memory will be lost. You need to write something like

```
char **tmp = realloc(array->elements, 2 * array->capacity * sizeof(char*));

if ( tmp != NULL )
{
    array->elements = tmp;
    array->capacity  *= 2;
}
```