# How should I dynamically allocate memory inside of a C function?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

I'm just looking for a better way to dynamically allocate an "array" in C. I'm used to C++, Rust and Python where you can just use vectors or lists and would really appreciate some feedback.

I've written a lexer to tokenise a given input (e.g. a text file). Additionally I needed a function to automatically proceed to the next token and collect all the tokens in an array and came up with the following:

```
Token* Lexer_Run(Lexer* lexer, int* destination_size)
{
    int i = 0, size = 128;
    Token* destination = (Token*)malloc(size * sizeof(Token));
    if (destination == NULL)
        die("Memory allocation failed!");

    Token token = Lexer_Advance(lexer);

    while (token.type != TOKEN_EOF)
    {
        if (i >= size - 1)
        {
            size *= 2;
            destination = (Token*)realloc(destination, size * sizeof(Token));
            if (destination == NULL)
                die("Memory allocation failed!");
        }

        destination[i] = token;
        i++;

        token = Lexer_Advance(lexer);
    }

    destination = (Token*)realloc(destination, i * sizeof(Token));
    if (destination == NULL)
        die("Memory allocation failed!");
    *destination_size = i;

    return destination;
}
```

This works but perhaps there is a better way of accomplishing this? This looks too complex for such a simple task but maybe that's just C... Also I don't like the fact that I essentially have to abuse an argument to the function (destination_size) as a "return value".

Comment: [Should I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/)

Comment: looks fine to me on the surface, `realloc` is how you expand your memory segment, altho you could be doing this is a [safer way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006707/proper-usage-of-realloc). A linked list (of tokens) is another option, perhaps that would serve your needs better?

Comment: @Chris Cheers; I was told to cast malloc results back in university :D

Comment: If the data is needed by the entire program, one way is to use a global array with a size that you estimate (perhaps empirically) to be adequate but not wasteful. When you use the next element, you check you don't exceed the array bounds. Dynamic memory is suited to a program's local demands for memory that may change during the life of the program. Some use the mantra "global bad" but in the right situation it is appropriate.

Comment: @KilakOriginal University will teach you a lot of bad programming habits. To the question, you can also consider a linked list rather than reallocating memory. Depends on your needs.

Comment: You could embed `destination` and `destination_size` into the `Lexer` struct. Then, you don't need to use separate variables. This might make it tidier. Or, you could create a new struct: `typedef struct { Token *token_list; size_t token_count; size_t token_cap; } TokenList;`

Comment: Another option is instead of *doubling* the size of the array (which may break the system) is to allocate a fixed number of extra records each time. For example if the total requirement might be anywhere between 1 and 50000 records, allocate in chunks of 10000 records.

Comment: @WeatherVane The conventional wisdom (from an article I read recently) is that a multiplier of 1.5 is optimal. But, I've always done the fixed increment size for the reason you mentioned. I prefer that. I've even done something where it takes timestamps and calculates the increment size based on only having to grow the buffer after a certain amount of time (e.g. once per second). The increment value is adjusted dynamically to achieve this.

Comment: @CraigEstey Concerning * 2 or * 1.5, etc.   Using `(2*n + 1)` as in 0,1,3,7,15,31,.... has the nice property of starting at 0 and eventually trying `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @yano I just came across this the other day: [Bjarne Stroustrup: Why you should avoid Linked Lists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo) which totally surprised me. I think the actual use case indicates which to use: array or list. It the element is a small scalar, arrays may win. If the item is a large struct, list may win.

Comment: @WeatherVane perhaps double until you reach a certain max size, then grow by fixed chunks?

Comment: @Chris whatever strategy should balance the avaiable resources with the expected demand.

Answer (score 1):

> This looks too complex for such a simple task but maybe that's just C.

C makes you do what a lot of other languages do for you. We can make things simpler by separating the code for the array from the code which uses the array.

> Also I don't like the fact that I essentially have to abuse an argument to the function (destination_size) as a "return value".

That's not an uncommon technique, but here are two alternatives.

### A Dynamic Array Struct

As you've noticed, a dynamic array needs multiple values:

1. Capacity
2. Size
3. Memory

You can define a struct which contains all these. This is safer and more convenient.

```
// I'm using char * as a stand in for Token
typedef struct {
  size_t capacity;
  size_t size;
  char **contents;
} dynamic_array;
```

This also offers us the opportunity to define all the dynamic array operations as separate functions. This makes the code easier to understand and debug.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
  size_t capacity;
  size_t size;
  char **contents;
} DynamicArray;

void array_resize(DynamicArray *array, size_t new_capacity) {
    char **new_contents = realloc(array->contents, sizeof(char*) * new_capacity);
    if( new_contents == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed\n");
    }
    
    array->contents = new_contents;
    array->capacity = new_capacity;
    if( new_capacity < array->size ) {
        array->size = new_capacity;
    }
}

void array_grow(DynamicArray *array, size_t grow_by) {
    array_resize(array, array->capacity + grow_by);
}

void array_append(DynamicArray* array, char *item) {
    if( array->capacity <= array->size ) {
        // realloc'ing every time can fragment memory.
        // Here we double each time to avoid that, but has its own issues.
        // There are many different growth strategies.
        array_grow(array, array->capacity);
    }
    
    array->contents[array->size] = item;
    array->size += 1;
}

DynamicArray* array_new(size_t capacity) {
    DynamicArray *array = malloc(sizeof(DynamicArray));
    array->capacity = capacity;
    array->size = 0;
    array->contents = malloc(sizeof(char*) * array->capacity);
    
    return array;
}

void array_free_content(DynamicArray *array) {
    for( size_t i = 0; i < array->size; i++) {
        free(array->contents[i]);
    }
}

void array_free(DynamicArray* array, bool free_content) {
    if( free_content ) {
        array_free_content(array);
    }
    free(array->contents);
    free(array);
}

void array_debug(DynamicArray* array) {
    printf("size: %zu, capacity: %zu, contents: %p\n", array->size, array->capacity, array->contents);
}

int main()
{
    // Allocate an array with a capacity of 2
    DynamicArray *array = array_new(2);

    // Add three items, 3rd append grows the array.
    array_append(array, "foo");
    array_append(array, "bar");
    array_append(array, "baz");
    
    // size: 3, capacity: 4, contents: ....
    array_debug(array);
    
    for( size_t i = 0; i < array->size; i++) {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", i, array->contents[i]);
    }
    
    // In this case, the strings were not allocated so they should not be freed.
    array_free(array, false);
}
```

[Demonstration](https://www.online-cpp.com/MFhWbquHQv).

At which point you're defining your own dynamic array library, so you might as well [use an existing one](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.PtrArray.html).

### A Linked List

Instead of an array, use a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). This is easily grown and traversed, but looking up specific indexes is an O(n) operation, while the same lookups are O(1) in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// char * is a stand in for Token.
typedef struct Node {
    char* content;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node* node_new(char* content) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->content = content;
    node->next = NULL;

    return node;
}

Node* node_add(Node* head, char* content) {
    Node *tail = node_new(content);
    head->next = tail;
    return tail;
}

void node_free(Node* head, bool free_content) {
    while(head) {
        Node *next = head->next;
        if( free_content ) {
            free(head->content);
        }
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}

void node_debug(Node *head) {
    for( Node *node = head; node; node = node->next ) {
        printf("node: %p, next: %p, content: %s\n", node, node->next, node->content);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Keep track of the head and the tail, so you might add another struct to do that.
    Node *head = node_new("foo");
    Node *tail = node_add(head, "bar");
    tail = node_add(tail, "baz");

    node_debug(head);

    for( Node *node = head; node; node = node->next ) {
        puts(node->content);
    }

    // The content was not allocated, so we do not free it.
    node_free(head, false);
}
```

[Demonstration](https://www.online-cpp.com/XDyC2mILh8).

Again, this is a good exercise, but you should use an existing [single](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.SList.html) or [double linked list](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.List.html).

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine except:

- Don't cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc`.
- Assign the result of `realloc` to a different pointer so that you don't lose the original pointer if it fails. Once you know it has succeeded you can re-assign the original. In your case you `die` on failure of `realloc`, but because `destination` is now `NULL` you cannot free the already allocated memory.
- Use `size_t` rather than `int` when dealing with sizes of arrays. It's the right thing to do, and if you turn on (and turn up!) warnings this should save you some grief. If scanning/printing be prepared to use a `%zu` format specifier.

```c
Token* Lexer_Run(Lexer* lexer, size_t* destination_size)
{
    size_t i = 0, size = 128;
    Token* destination = malloc(size * sizeof(*destination));
    if (destination == NULL)
        die("Memory allocation failed!");

    Token token = Lexer_Advance(lexer);

    while (token.type != TOKEN_EOF)
    {
        if (i >= size - 1)
        {
            size *= 2;
            Token* temp = realloc(destination, size * sizeof(Token));
            if (temp == NULL) {
                // We should clean up the already allocated 
                // memory before dieing.
                free(destination); 
                die("Memory allocation failed!");
            }

            destination = temp;
        }

        destination[i] = token;
        i++;

        token = Lexer_Advance(lexer);
    }

    Token* temp = realloc(destination, i * sizeof(Token));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        // We should clean up the already allocated 
        // memory before dieing.
        free(destination);
        die("Memory allocation failed!");
    }

    destination = temp;
    *destination_size = i;

    return destination;
}
```

As a further step, you may wish to break this logic out into a vector structure and functions which manipulate it.

As suggested, a linked list might be another data structure worth investigating, but only if you don't need random access to the contents.

The growth rate of x2 is sane, but [there may be more efficient factors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100311/what-is-the-ideal-growth-rate-for-a-dynamically-allocated-array)

Answer (score 0):

> How should I dynamically allocate memory inside of a C function?

`malloc()` / `calloc()`, possibly supplemented by `realloc()` are the conventional and idiomatic way to perform dynamic memory allocation in C.  Indeed, the ISO committee in charge of the language spec has long resisted adding any features that provide dynamically-allocated objects any other way, though other efforts such as POSIX and GNU have not been quite as reticent.

> I [...] came up with the following [...]

That looks like a pretty good implementation to me.  I can see that you have some experience, as neophytes usually try to allocate space one item at a time, whereas you have taken a more efficient approach.  Personally, though, I probably would not bother with that final `realloc()`.

> This works but perhaps there is a better way of accomplishing this?

"Better" is a matter of opinion, but your approach is along the same lines as I would use.  There are a couple of other details the could be improved, but I'll not go into those because I take yours to be mostly a high-level question.

> This looks too complex for such a simple task but maybe that's just C...

You've been spoiled by some very high-level languages.  C is still a HLL itself, but not nearly so much so as idiomatic C++ (for example).  What you've written is not unreasonably complex for C.

> Also I don't like the fact that I essentially have to abuse an argument to the function (destination_size) as a "return value".

Well now, "abuse" is a strong word.  It's a perfectly normal usage of C for a function to communicate with its caller via pointers provided as arguments.  That mechanism can be abused, I suppose, but I don't see anything about your code that I would remotely characterize that way.

Nevertheless, you do have other options.  For example, you could define a structure type encompassing a pointer to the first element of your dynamically allocated array and an element count.  You could then convey both pieces of information back to the caller at once by returning an instance of that structure by value, or you could allocate space for one dynamically and return a pointer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to include the last token with the TOKEN_EOF indicator at the end of your array. Having an guard or end of array indicator can make loops a bit more intuitive.

I'd also consider have two loops for filling the array with tokens, an inner loop that just pulls in tokens and puts them into the array and an outer loop that checks whether you're done or not and if not does the `realloc()`.

I've also made changes so that the function `Lexer_Run()` will do as much as it is capable of doing and returning those results even if incomplete. No telling what kind of cleanup you might need to do in the case of a failure.

Finally, I've become something of a fan of using a `struct` to return not only the data from a function but also any other management information needed such as an error indicator.

This is a complete example that I used to test out some ideas. I've tried to comment things to be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct {
    int type;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} Token;

typedef struct {
    Token *tok;
    int   nTok;
    int   iError;  // 0 finished, no error; 1 finished, last resize failed; 2 not finished, realloc() error; 3 not started, memory error
} RunRet;

#define TOKEN_EOF -1

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char tag;
} Lexer;

Token Lexer_Advance(Lexer* l) {
    static int ix = 0;
    Token jj = { 0 };

    // do lexer advance stuff
    jj.a = ix;
    if (ix > 256) jj.type = TOKEN_EOF;

    ix++;

    return jj;
}

int die(const char* reason) {
    Token* x = NULL;
    printf("die because of %s\n", reason);
    x->type = 0;  // cause a crash for the debugger to find

    return 0;
}

RunRet Lexer_Run(Lexer* lexer)
{
    int size = 128;  // starting value for number of allocated elements
    Token* destination = malloc(size * sizeof(Token));
    int iError = 0;  // error indicator. assume we finish unless we find out otherwise
    int iCount = 0;  // count of tokens in the array

    if (destination == NULL) {
        iError = 3;   // not finished because we were unable to start
    }
    else {
        Token const tokenX = { TOKEN_EOF, 0 };   // empty token to indicate end of list.
        Token token = tokenX;                    // working token variable
        do {
            do {
                destination[iCount++] = token = Lexer_Advance(lexer);
                // fill all of the array except the last entry so that we
                // can put a TOKEN_EOF indicator there if there's a realloc() error.
            } while (token.type != TOKEN_EOF && iCount < size - 1);

            if (token.type != TOKEN_EOF)
            {
                // at the last good array element but more to do so reallocate or just end it
                size *= 2;   // may choose some other increasing function besides just doubling the size
                Token *dest = realloc(destination, size * sizeof(Token));
                if (dest == NULL) {
                    iError = 2;   // not finished and unable to continue due to realloc() failure
                    destination[iCount++] = token = tokenX;  // realloc() failed so end the list and end the loop
                }
                else {
                    destination = dest;   // realloc() worked so lets update our array pointer
                }
            }
            else {
                // we are finished now lets resize the array to reduce memory usage.
                // this may not be necessary so we may want to just remove this step.
                Token* dest = realloc(destination, iCount * sizeof(Token));
                if (dest == NULL) {
                    iError = 1;    // finished but unable to resize the array to its final size
                }
                else {
                    destination = dest;
                }
            }
        } while (token.type != TOKEN_EOF);
    }

    RunRet ret = { destination, iCount, iError };

    return ret;
}

int CleanupArray(Token* p) {
    if (p) {
        Token* pSave = p;
        // clean up each array element
        for (; p->type != TOKEN_EOF; p++) {
            // clean up any storage used by this token pointed to by p
        }
        free(pSave);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    RunRet ret = { 0 };
    Lexer lex = { 0 };

    ret = Lexer_Run(&lex);

    switch (ret.iError) {
    case 0:    // finished and we were able to resize the array.
    case 1:    // finished but we were unable to resize the array
        // successful run so lets do things with our list
        for (Token* p = ret.tok; p->type != TOKEN_EOF; p++) {
            // do things with this token pointed to by p
            printf("%p:%4.4d ", p, p->a);
        }
        CleanupArray(ret.tok);
        break;
    case 2:   // not finished but we do have some good data.
        // lets do things with what data we have
        for (Token* p = ret.tok; p->type != TOKEN_EOF; p++) {
            // do things with this token pointed to by p
            printf("%p:%4.4d ", p, p->a);
        }
        CleanupArray(ret.tok);
        break;
    case 3:   // not even started and there is no data
        // nothing to do and nothing to clean up
        break;
    default:
        die("unknown error status from Lexer_Run.");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest that `iError` member should be an enum, if only for expressiveness in being able to name the error states.

Comment: @Chris that is a good suggestion. Thank you.